# use range with stepsize in yaml file

Tags: python, range, yaml

In a .yaml file, I want to specify a range for a certain field, e.g., something like,

`list_field: range(10,50,5)`

In the above, I intend the `list_field` to be "pythonic" `range(10,50,5)`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

YAML does not have a way to specify ranges in [its specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), so if you want a language-agnostic way to specify range, you'd have to invent your own encoding on top of native YAML.  Some examples:

```
list_field:
  start: 10
  step: 5
  stop: 50
list_field2:
  range:
  - 10
  - 50
  - 5
list_field3: range(10,50,5)
```

If using something like [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), you could then use a [custom resolver and constructor](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers) to teach pyyaml how to always decode/encode these things as/from python range objects (python3) or python xrange objects (python2)

If you don't care about other languages, you could also always just store your ranges as serialized objects, e.g. using tags, e.g. `!!python/object/apply:builtins.range [10, 50, 5]`.  They won't look the prettiest, but will deserialize to a python `range` object without needing to write custom encoder/decoder code:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> print(yaml.dump({'list_field': range(10, 50, 5)}))
list_field: !!python/object/apply:builtins.range [10, 50, 5]
>>> print(yaml.load(yaml.dump({'list_field': range(10, 50, 5)})))
{'list_field': range(10, 50, 5)}
```

See also [How to specify ranges in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337020/how-to-specify-ranges-in-yaml)

Comment: If you come across this question now, note that using `yaml.load()` in newer versions of pyyaml (v4.x+) no longer works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054268/4659442. To get it to work you would have to use `yaml.unsafe_load()` (though you do so at your own risk).