# New PyYAML version breaks on most custom python objects - RepresenterError

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

About 5 hours ago, version `4.1.0` was released. It is breaking my unit tests. Here is a clean MVCE displaying this:

**Version 3.12:**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import yaml
>>> x = np.int64(2)
>>> yaml.dump(x, Dumper=yaml.Dumper)
'!!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar\n- !!python/object/apply:numpy.dtype\n  args: [i8, 0, 1]\n  state: !!python/tuple [3, <, null, null, null, -1, -1, 0]\n- !!binary |\n  AgAAAAAAAAA=\n'
```

**Version 4.1.0**:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import yaml
>>> x = np.int64(2)
>>> yaml.dump(x, Dumper=yaml.Dumper)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/foo/anaconda3/envs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 217, in dump
    return dump_all([data], stream, Dumper=Dumper, **kwds)
  File "/foo/anaconda3/envs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 196, in dump_all
    dumper.represent(data)
  File "/foo/anaconda3/envs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 26, in represent
    node = self.represent_data(data)
  File "/foo/anaconda3/envs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 57, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[None](self, data)
  File "/foo/anaconda3/envs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 229, in represent_undefined
    raise RepresenterError("cannot represent an object", data)
yaml.representer.RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', 2)
```

Is there a clear reason for why `PyYAML` no longer supports these object types?

Comment: PyYAML 4.1.0 [has been retracted](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/126#issuecomment-401175258) from PyPI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The breaking changes in 4.x were an attempt to resolve [CVE-2017-18342](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rprw-h62v-c2w7), which is the possibility of arbitrary code execution for untrusted inputs.

In PyYAML 4.x, `dump` is an alias for `safe_dump`, which won't handle arbitrary objects:

```
>>> yaml.dump is yaml.safe_dump
True
```

Use `danger_dump` for the old 3.x behaviour.

```
>>> yaml.danger_dump(x)
'!!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar\n- !!python/object/apply:numpy.dtype\n  args: [i8, 0, 1]\n  state: !!python/tuple [3, <, null, null, null, -1, -1, 0]\n- !!binary |\n  AgAAAAAAAAA=\n'
```

The same goes for `load`/`safe_load`. Can't find any docs or release notes for 4.1.0, I only found out by digging through the commits ([here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/commit/7b68405c81db889f83c32846462b238ccae5be80)).

> Is there a clear reason for why PyYAML no longer supports these object types?

Yes. `yaml.load` was allowing arbitrary code execution, and such a dangerous feature should be opt-in only, not possible to use by accident. Arguably, it should have been this way from the beginning.

---

In current PyYAML 5.x: instead of using different functions, you can specify the loader/dumper class as an argument:

```
yaml.dump(x, Dumper=yaml.Dumper)      # like "danger dump"
yaml.dump(x, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)  # like "safe_dump", won't dump python objs
```

As with 3.x, the "danger" dump is still the default in 5.x:

```
>>> yaml.dump(sys)
"!!python/module:sys ''\n"
>>> yaml.dump(sys, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)
RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', <module 'sys' (built-in)>)
```

Comment: As of yaml 5.3.1 I see only `dump` and `safe_dump`.  No `danger_dump`.  But this answer is correct in that you avoid `RepresenterError` using different functions.  In 5.3.1 `dump` works but you get errors using `safe_dump`.  Note that there is no real danger in *dump*, but exists with *load*.  I.e. you can "unsafe dump" to your heart's content - I use it to dump out object graphs that are not intended for reload.  But *load* is a security risk (if you're paranoid enough: even on *your* content - someone could alter a known-good dump file to fire attack code on its next load).

Comment: @JLPeyret  This Q&A is specific to the PyYAML 4.x releases, in 5.x the `yaml.dump` is similar to the 3.x behavior. But I'll add a section for 5.x to the answer.

Comment: Up to you, but this is an old question, on an old version.  The gist of your answer is still correct in 5.x in any case.  FWIW, the v5.3.1 module level functions that have `safe` in their names are `['safe_dump', 'safe_dump_all', 'safe_load', 'safe_load_all', 'unsafe_load', 'unsafe_load_all']`.